# Does 'Deutlich nicht' make sense?

Tags: english-to-german

It's supposed to mean 'Clearly not'.

Comment: If you give some context you will receive more qualified answers. The expression to chose depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Deutlich" means "clear" in the *sound* sense of the word, as in "loud and clear."

For "clearly not," you want a word that stands for "clear" in the *meaning* sense of the word.

Such words include "sicherlich," or even the similar-looking (and linguistically related)* "klar." That's why other posters suggested constructions like "Sicherlich nicht" or "Klar ist das nicht so," rather than "deutlich nicht."

If you want to use a form of "deutlich" in the meaning sense of the word, a better usage is "*ein*deutig nicht," which has the connotations of "*one* sense" in the context of clarity.

*See one of the comments (by Takkat).

Comment: "deutlich" does not only refer to sound, it's also used for meaning.

Comment: @Robert: Expanded the answer to clarify.

Comment: *Klar* is not only "similar-looking" it is the most obvious translation of *clear(ly)*. Both are etymologically derived from Latin *clarus*.

Comment: @Takkat: Added an asterisk with a reference to your comment.

Answer (score 5):

It is not correct.

The better version would be "Eindeutig nicht" or "Sicher(lich) nicht"

Comment: "Not correct" is perhaps a little bit too strong a verdict. "Very unusual" may be more appropriate.

Comment: I actually cannot think of a context where "Deutlich nicht" as a standalone expression is valid. In some sentences the word combination may occur, but that would not fit the stand alone expression "clearly not" - So "very unusual" would be misleading

Comment: Or "offensichtlich nicht".

Comment: You are right in claiming that "deutlich nicht" is hardly ever used in German everday and standard language. However, on the other hand, whoever anyway uses it will be understood without any problem. The audience may perhaps think "oh, strange way to say this", but anyway the message is delivered. And who knows, one day the expression may even become popular. Other formerly strange expressions have become: "am Ende des Tages", "etwas macht Sinn" - these came from Anglosaxonia, but today hardly anybody finds them silly anymore.

Comment: I'm German and I had no idea what "deutlich nicht" was supposed to mean until I read the explanation that it's meant to be "clearly not". So, I fully agree with Vertixico.

Comment: What is unintelligible in "deutlich nicht"? That's "nicht" plus "deutlich", similar to "nicht" plus "sicherlich". The meaning is clear from the primary meaning of the individual words (even though it is not a common expression, as already admitted).

Comment: Just form the words, the context is not clear in german - unless you are aware of the english expression "clearly not". This is an additional indicator, that "deutlich nicht" is not working in german for the average german speaker

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context,

> - [keineswegs](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/keineswegs)
> - [überhaupt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueberhaupt_vollends_besonders_insgemein) nicht
> - [ganz und gar](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ganz_und_gar) nicht

may be good translations of *»clearly not«*.

---

*»Deutlich nicht«* (here not meant as a translation for *»clearly not«*) makes sense in a case of repetition and emphasis:

> »Meinen Sie, Frau Merkel hat deutlich besser abgeschnitten als Herr
>   Schulz?«
>   »*Deutlich* nicht.«

However, *»deutlich nicht«* can also serve as an uncommon translation for *»clearly not«*:

> »Hat er seine Ziele erreicht?«
>   »Deutlich nicht.« (*Short for:* »Nein, er hat seine Ziele deutlich nicht erreicht.«)

A common answer in this case would be: *»Bei Weitem nicht.«*

Answer (score 0):

It is almost correct but we'd use the closest possible translation to clear:

### [klar](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/klar)

Then we may say (in colloquial speech!):

> Klar ist das nicht so. Es ist nämlich ganz anders.